# Modifying train_test_split function

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

Can I split a data set into training and test sets based on index value (every 10th row as train data and the remaining as test data) using `train_test_split()` rather than passing `test_size` and `random_state` arguments?

Comment: your question is not clear enough... could you please give more details

Comment: I know that train_test_split() under sklearn library splits the dataset into training and test data based on test_size argument. If test_size is 0.2, it splits the dataset in the ratio 80:20. But if I want to split every 10th row of the dataset as train data and the remaining as test, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok try this, you can use `::n`, it will return every nth that you will specify, here is the example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'number': np.arange(100), })
```

if we want to get values every 10th :

```
print(df[::10])
```

result:

```
    number
0        0
10      10
20      20
30      30
40      40
50      50
60      60
70      70
80      80
90      90
```

you can do same thing with numpy array:

```
np.arange(100)

array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
       34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
       51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67,
       68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84,
       85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99])
```

every 9th value:

```
np.arange(100)[::9]
```

output:

```
array([ 0,  9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81, 90, 99])
```

edit:

```
def getting_train_val(dataframe, interval=10):
    x_valid = dataframe[::interval]
    x_test = dataframe[~ dataframe(dataframe[::interval])].dropna()
    return x_valid, x_test
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I believe this cannot be done using train_test_split function. Using df[::10] gets me the train dataset. But how can I get the remaining rows into the test dataset?

Comment: Yeah, it works! Thanks for the help! :) I just realized using:  for index, row in df.iterrows():   X_train = df[(df.index)% 5 != 0] also serves the purpose :)

Comment: great!=) happy coding!

Comment: @RachaelE Please accept H.Bukharis answer as your solution so that others can see that the matter is resolved. Thanks!

Comment: @petezurich  Accepted it :)